# WFLYEJB0029: Could not restore timer from ... com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jboss, wildfly

In my Java Enterprise Application running on Wildfly 10, I'm retrieving constantly the same error    `'Could not restore timer from /opt/wildfly/standalone/data/timer-service-data/... .xml: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog.`

```
17:41:43,482 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-8) EE modules: [BeanDeploymentModule [id=deployment.CTGEar.ear.CTGRest.war:main, web=true, managers=[CTGEar.ear/CTGRest.war]], BeanDeploymentModule [id=deployment.CTGEar.ear.CTGWeb.war:main, web=true, managers=[/content/CTGEar.ear/CTGWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-6.0.jar, CTGEar.ear/CTGWeb.war, /content/CTGEar.ear/CTGWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/CTGWeb-1.3.2-SNAPSHOT.jar, deployment.CTGEar.ear.CTGWeb.war:main.additionalClasses]], BeanDeploymentModule [id=deployment.CTGEar.ear:main, web=false, managers=[CTGEar.ear]], BeanDeploymentModule [id=deployment.CTGEar.ear.CTGService.jar:main, web=false, managers=[/content/CTGEar.ear/CTGService.jar]], BeanDeploymentModule [id=deployment.CTGEar.ear.CTGDAO.jar:main, web=false, managers=[/content/CTGEar.ear/CTGDAO.jar]], BeanDeploymentModule [id=BeanDeploymentModules.DEFAULT, web=false, managers=[org.hibernate.validator:main.additionalClasses, com.sun.jsf-impl:main.additionalClasses, org.jboss.as.jsf:main.additionalClasses, org.hibernate.validator.cdi:main.additionalClasses, org.jberet.jberet-core:main.additionalClasses, org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-cdi:main.additionalClasses]]]
17:41:43,595 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) ServiceLocator bean is a @Startup (a.k.a init-on-startup) bean, creating/getting the singleton instance
17:41:43,595 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) SparkSingleton bean is a @Startup (a.k.a init-on-startup) bean, creating/getting the singleton instance
17:41:43,631 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Reflection] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WELD-000620: interface javax.enterprise.inject.Intercepted is not declared @Target(METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE). Weld will use this annotation, however this may make the application unportable.
17:41:43,632 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Reflection] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WELD-000620: interface javax.enterprise.inject.Decorated is not declared @Target(METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE). Weld will use this annotation, however this may make the application unportable.
17:41:43,653 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.timer] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) WFLYEJB0029: Could not restore timer from /opt/wildfly/standalone/data/timer-service-data/CTGEar.CTGService.CdetsDefectService/3ce1c92f-86fa-4ebf-a7b0-732ae1a3aa2e.xml: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedEOF(StreamScanner.java:685)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleEOF(BasicStreamReader.java:2141)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2047)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1131)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextTag(BasicStreamReader.java:1154)
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:67)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.persistence.filestore.FileTimerPersistence.loadTimersFromFile(FileTimerPersistence.java:370)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.persistence.filestore.FileTimerPersistence.getTimers(FileTimerPersistence.java:333)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.persistence.filestore.FileTimerPersistence.loadActiveTimers(FileTimerPersistence.java:274)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl.getActivePersistentTimers(TimerServiceImpl.java:952)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl.restoreTimers(TimerServiceImpl.java:692)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl.activate(TimerServiceImpl.java:225)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.EJBComponent.start(EJBComponent.java:543)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.start(SingletonComponent.java:133)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$1.run(ComponentStartService.java:54)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)`
```

...and repeats Exception more times.

Anyone know what could be the cause of the error?

Comment: I am having the same error. DId you find a resolution?

Comment: I'm giving you an update ASAP. I'll try the below response. This is a headache in my company

Comment: @donlys The error was produced due to an inappropriate shutdown . Removing the timers under `/opt/wildfly/standalone/data/timer-service-data/` or modifying it to have a proper EOF  should work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I stopped wildfly and deleted all the folders/subfolders/files under /opt/wildfly/standalone/data/timer-service-data/. After restarting wildfly the error was gone. All the timers were stopped as well - which I had to restart to bring the system back to the original state.

Comment: I got the same error which often appears. Is there any permanent resolution?

Comment: @sipekmichal Probably there's a way to disable persistence timers or something else. I'd also like to know a way to do that, let me know if you find it please.